# Limiting download and upload speeds based on wifi network?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

I alternate between my home network (150mbit down) and my friend's network (10mbit down, barely enough to stream videos), and I'd like to be able to limit my download and upload speeds based on which network my laptop is connected to. Is there a way to do this in Windows 10?

I realize I could probably do this on her router, but I'd prefer doing it on the client - that way I can have rules for other networks if need be.

Comment: With Windows 10 you may try setting your friend's connection as a "Metered connection". This will suspend most background system communication when you are connected to that network. Otherwise, you'll probably require a third-part firewall of some sort to further limit bandwidth use on that network.

Comment: I tried using that, but I want a lot more control. If I'm downloading a file on her network, everything else slows down or outright stops.

Comment: You can get file download apps with bandwidth limiters, but anything else really needs organising on her router; QoS, WMM etc

Comment: As you note, this is better accomplished on the friend's router. Most solutions online are based on configuring QoS on the router, and because QoS is a mature solution, there does not appear to be much development of on-PC solutions.

Comment: Is there a download manager that can do this based on what wifi network you're connected to?

Comment: None that I know of, just a manual switch, restrict/unlimited